# In a microservice architecture, can individual microservices contain any configuration file? Is keeping a small config a good practice?

Tags: microservices, configuration

I thought, In a microservice architecture, only the "Configuration Server" will be responsible for providing configuration to individual microservices even if it's a small config. So that we can change it from a central point without going through individual microservices for changing the config.

Just want to clear my doubt. Thank you.

Comment: Not all configuration can or should be painted with the same brush. Some configuration is inherently bound to a specific service, other configuration is inherently related to the shared infrastructure, other configuration might be shared only by nodes of the same microservice. Decisions will vary based on what kind of config we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of a microservice architecture is to have independently deployable services. This it at the opposite of a centralized legacy monolith.

It is not necessarily wrong to try to manage configuration centrally using some shared infrastructure. But newer versions of a microservice could be deployed along with older one that could have different or additional configuration parameters. Versions of an existing microservice could be deployed with different configuration settings to experiment/tune parameters, or for specialization purpose. If you can’t manage these cases with your centralised configuration management, it’s certainly a valid readon to allow for local configuration elements.